# Go Redis Loading

Tags: go, redis

I am trying to load 200 million keys into redis and usually start to get an error at around 31 million keys and have to stop.I am using golang and the redis library "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"

I set up a connection pool as so:

```
func newPool(server string) *redis.Pool {
    return &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle: 3,
        MaxActive: 10,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial: func () (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", server)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            return c, err
        },
        TestOnBorrow: func(c redis.Conn, t time.Time) error {
            _, err := c.Do("PING")
            return err
        },
    }
}
```

I then try to fill up redis with values with this function:

```
func RedisServerBatchLoadKeys(rtbExchange string, keys []string){
  redisLock.Lock()
  defer redisLock.Unlock()
  retry := 0
  for {
    conn := GetConnOrPanic(rtbExchange)
    defer conn.Close()
    conn.Send("MULTI")
    for _, key := range keys {
      conn.Send("SET", key, maxCount)
      conn.Send("EXPIRE", key, numSecondsExpire)
    }
    _, err := conn.Do("EXEC")
    if err == nil {
      break
    } else if !(err == io.EOF) {
      CheckRedisError(err, rtbExchange, "Could not load batch")
    } else {
      retry ++
    }
    if retry >= 10 {
      CheckRedisError(err, rtbExchange, "Could not load batch - 10 retries")
    }
  }
}
```

I have been getting numerous errors such as:

- read tcp 10.249.15.194:6379: connection reset by peer
- dial tcp 10.249.15.194:6379: connection refused
- redis#RedisError :  EOF

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or do I have to add in more error checks (aside from the EOF that I added).

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know what `GetConnOrPanic()` does, but are you trying to SET millions of values in one single transaction? Put each SET/EXPIRE into a single MULTI/EXEC transaction.

Comment: Sorry, I set them 100 at a time

Comment: It seems you are getting a new connection from the pool on every iteration without closing it. The defer only closes it on function exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess: 200 million keys is a lot. Do you have enough memory for that size database?

The Redis docs say:

> Redis can handle up to 2^32 keys, and was tested in practice to handle at least 250 million of keys per instance.
>
> In other words your limit is likely the available memory in your system.

They also say:

> What happens if Redis runs out of memory?
>
> Redis will either be killed by the Linux kernel OOM killer, crash with an error, or will start to slow down.

It seems plausible to me that you're not able to connect because the server is actually down. Perhaps it gets restarted, and the next time you run your script it gets to the same place every time because that's when you run out of memory.

If this is your problem there are a couple things you could try:

1. Use a redis hash which can store data more efficiently. See http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization
2. Partition (shard) your data set across multiple servers (for example if you had 4 servers you could take your `key % 4` to determine which redis server to store under) If what you're going for is O(1) lookup you'll still get that, though you've made your system more brittle because there are multiple points of failure.

Comment: I did eventually figure out that we were running out of memory on the redis-server. Thanks for the help. Going to move to redis hashes.